# JSP Javascript validation function and reset function not working

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a validate function and a reset function confirming whether to confirm and they are both not working. Please help. I have tried more ways of referencing to the input of the html form i.e. getElementById()function, getElementByName(), document.form.inputElementName.value, document.forms["formName"]["inpuElementName"].value.  NONE IS WORKING!!!! PLEASE HELP!!!! Its a class project

The Javascript:

```
      <script type=text/javascript>
     function validateInventory() {
    var imei_no = document.form.imei_no.value;
    var phone_name = document.form.phone_name.value;
    var phone_storage = document.form.phone_storage.value;
    var phone_color = document.form.phone_color.value;
    var phone_buyingprice = document.form.phone_buyingprice.value;
var valid = true;

    if (imei_no.value.length > 15 || imei_no.value.length <= 0||imei_no) {
        alert("Invalid No. of digits in IMEI");
        form.imei_no.focus();
        valid = false;

    } else {
        if (isNaN(imei_no) == true
                || isNaN(phone_buyingprice) == true) {
            alert("Please enter number value in IMEI/Buying Price!");
            imei_no.focus();
            phone_buyingprice.focus();
            valid = false;
        } else if (imei_no = null ||imei_no = 0 || phone_name_value == ""
                || phone_storage_value == "" || phone_color_value == ""
                || phone_buyingprice_value == 0|| phone_buyingprice_value == null) {
            alert("Some entries are empty. Please recheck your Input");
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    var cofirmInput= window.confirm("Is your Input correct?");
    if(confirmInput==true){
        alert("Input succesful!!!");
        return valid; 
    }else{
        valid=false;
    }

};
function resetInventory() {
    var resetForm = window
            .confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?");
    if (resetForm == true) {
        alert("Reset Successful!!!");
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
        };
};
```

This is the HTML Form in My JSP:

```
<form action=# method=post name=InventoryForm id=InventoryForm
                onreset="return resetInventory()"
                onsubmit="return validateInventory()">
                <table border="1" cellpadding="5" id=InventoryFormTable>
                    <tr>
                        <th>IMEI NO</th>
                        <th>PHONE NAME</th>
                        <th>PHONE STORAGE</th>
                        <th>PHONE COLOR</th>
                        <th>PHONE BUYING PRICE</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><input type=text name=imei_no id=imei_no></td>
                        <td><select name=phone_name id=phone_name>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value="iPhone X">iPhone X</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 8">iPhone 8</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 8 Plus">iPhone 8Plus</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 7">iPhone 7</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 7 Plus">iPhone 7Plus</option>
                                <option value="iPhone SE">iPhone SE</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 6">iPhone 6</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 6 Plus">iPhone 6Plus</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 6s">iPhone 6s</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 6s Plus">iPhone 6sPlus</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 5">iPhone 5</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 5s">iPhone 5s</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 5c">iPhone 5c</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 4">iPhone 4</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 4s">iPhone 4s</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 3G">iPhone 3G</option>
                                <option value="iPhone 3GS">iPhone 3GS</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><select name=phone_storage id=phone_storage>
                                <option value=""></option>
                                <option value=16GB>16 GB</option>
                                <option value=3216GB>32 GB</option>
                                <option value=64GB>64 GB</option>
                                <option value=128GB>128 GB</option>
                                <option value=256GB>256 GB</option>
                        </select></td>
                        <td><input type=text name=phone_color id=phone_color></td>
                        <td><input type=text name=phone_buyingingprice
                            id=phone_buyingingprice></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td colspan=6><div class=button>
                                <input type=submit id=submit value=submit>
                                &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <input type=reset
                                    id=reset value=reset>
                            </div></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>




            </form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you normally get values.

HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="something" id="somethingID" value="value" />
```

JS:

```
var somethingValue = document.getElementById("somethingID").value;
```

However if you specifically want values from when you submit your form you can get it easily by adding some simple JQuery, this is what I used before in a project of mine

HTML:

```
<form id="firstForm" action="actionpage.php" method="POST" >
    <textarea name="userInput" id="userTextArea"></textarea>
    <select id="userOptions">//dynamically filled</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Input user" />
</form>
```

JQuery:

```
function testFunction() {
$('#firstForm').submit(function() {
   var user = $('#userInput').val();
   alert(user);
});
}
```

Comment: As I hav said in my description of the problem, I have tried almost all methods of retrieving input values; getElementById()function, getElementByName(), document.form.inputElementName.value, document.forms["formName"]["inpuElementName"].value. NONE IS WORKING!!!! :-(

Comment: @PharisMukui How about my method with JQuery? can you retrieve your data with that?

Comment: Actually I changed the retrival method to getElementById() and it worked!! hehe. funny thing is, its not validating everything- one of the fields is not being validated. I didnt try the jQuery one.

Comment: How do you come up with a validation function using the jQuery you wrote?

Comment: @PharisMukui I didn't write anything for a validation function. Your question was why you didn't receive any values of the inputs from your HTML code. So I provided you with a way to retrieve these values. I thought your validation function would work if you had these values.

Comment: okay. thanks. right now I am having a problem with getting form data from html form using javascript and posting it to a java class (javabean) using javascript after validating using javascript. Could you be any help?

Comment: create a new question about it and provide the code. It is really hard to just improvise code to help when we don't know what you have done. If you created the new question and no one helps you out feel free to post the link to it here and i'll have a look. @PharisMukui

Comment: Okay. Lemme keep trying to solve it first then I will let you know